# If traceroute result returns more than one gateway in one hop, what is the path of the destination host?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I performed trace route in Linux, the traceroute result give me more than one gateway in each hop. How can I find the routing path to my destination? Please refer below output:

```
traceroute to ipv4.google.com (216.58.199.142), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.10.20.1 (10.10.20.1)  0.947 ms  0.833 ms  0.870 ms
 2  abts-tn-dynamic-1.64.65.182-airtelbroadband.in (182.65.64.1)  5.296 ms  5.235 ms  4.962 ms
 3  125.17.96.17 (125.17.96.17)  5.409 ms  5.012 ms  125.17.103.181 (125.17.103.181)  7.465 ms
 4  182.79.198.22 (182.79.198.22)  4.839 ms  182.79.239.193 (182.79.239.193)  5.631 ms  182.79.198.26 (182.79.198.26)  8.211 ms
 5  72.14.211.198 (72.14.211.198)  5.258 ms  6.221 ms  5.345 ms
 6  182.79.177.69 (182.79.177.69)  11.637 ms  182.79.142.222 (182.79.142.222)  6.840 ms  182.79.177.69 (182.79.177.69)  10.703 ms
 7  216.239.41.84 (216.239.41.84)  29.267 ms  209.85.247.252 (209.85.247.252)  95.052 ms  209.85.255.160 (209.85.255.160)  29.631 ms
 8  108.170.248.193 (108.170.248.193)  32.930 ms  74.125.242.131 (74.125.242.131)  6.579 ms  108.170.248.209 (108.170.248.209)  33.016 ms
 9  72.14.236.75 (72.14.236.75)  29.411 ms  37.831 ms  108.170.248.209 (108.170.248.209)  29.900 ms
10  108.170.248.209 (108.170.248.209)  32.564 ms  bom07s01-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.142)  26.744 ms  108.170.248.193 (108.170.248.193)  33.178 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be several paths.

Many carriers use ECMP or another multipath/load-balancing technology; usually the same stream (i.e. same source/destination IP, same protocol, same source/dest port numbers) takes the same path, but packets with a different port number may take a different path. (Sometimes the paths might lead to redundant routers in the same location – or to different cities – or even to different carriers. It's not unusual to see e.g. odd IP addresses going through Telia and even addresses going through Cogent.)

Linux *traceroute* by default uses UDP probes with incrementing port numbers, which means each probe can get assigned a different path if it goes through an ECMP router.

For a start, you could switch traceroute to use either **`--icmp`** probes (as Windows does) or **`--udp`** with a static port number. These both should be unaffected by ECMP; they won't show all paths but they should at least stick to the same path during the entire trace.

More advanced approaches would be tools such as ***paris-traceroute*** or ***dublin-traceroute*,** both of which claim to be able to map out *all* paths somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the same you said but I can't find the perfect path . Can you please tell the accurate way to find the path of the traceroute?

Comment: How do you know there even _is_ a "perfect path"?

Comment: perfect path means i want to show a result of each hops address & name

Comment: But that's what traceroute already shows.

Comment: traceroute to ipv4.google.com (216.58.199.142), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  10.10.20.1 (10.10.20.1)  0.947 ms  0.833 ms  0.870 ms
 2  abts-tn-dynamic-1.64.65.182-airtelbroadband.in (182.65.64.1)  5.296 ms  5.235 ms  4.962 ms
 3   4 
 5 
 6  
 7  
 8  
 9  
10  108.170.248.209 (108.170.248.209)  32.564 ms  bom07s01-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.142)  26.744 ms  108.170.248.193 (108.170.248.193)  33.178 ms
# take above example if some hop have 2 or 3 gateways what is mean by that?

Comment: It literally means that there are multiple paths! Some traceroute probes took path A and some took path B, and both are equally valid.

Comment: okay then if the probs are having different path , how can I ensure and print the path in TR98 paremeters?